# How do you say mixer in chinese?

Tags: translation

I was wondering how to say and write mixer in Chinese? This is the type of mixer I'm asking about:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

For a general and literal translation, the answer is exactly what @Tang Ho had mentioned： `搅拌机`

However, in regard to the specific type of model you referred, `打蛋器 Eggbeater` may be a better translation with less ambiguity in daily life.

That is because, `搅拌机` is often interpreted as something like:

[image: 搅拌机]
[image: 搅拌机]

while by searching `打蛋器`, the following content can be most likely found:

[image: 打蛋器]
[image: 打蛋器]

Answer (score 0):

On http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php , input 'mixer' in the searching field, choose 'English meaning' and search. It will display the results related to 'mixer'

[攪拌機](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/14251/) :mixer; blender

[攪拌器](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/36355/) :beater; blender; mixer